# How to customize my own Facebook Login button?

Tags: authentication, facebook

*When the user loads the page in their browser, the JavaScript SDK renders the Login Button on your page*

What if I don't want to use their button?

How to customize my own Facebook Login button?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override the CSS. Try using Firebug or the equivalent tool ("Inspect Element") in other browsers to see how it's done. The button is on your site, thus your CSS is taken into consideration. If you make it more specific than the CSS from Facebook, your CSS will take precedence. For  example: include the class name or id of an outer element.

Comment: Doesn't this break their TOS?